# Is there incompatibility between apps built using NDK 9 for Android 5.0 or superior?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm making a research about if there is any problem in compiling native code for Android 5 or superior using NDK 9 but couldn't yet find any answer.
I already made a long search in source.android.com, [this](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#platform-code-names-versions-api-levels-and-ndk-releases) page was the closer I could get to answering but it is not clear yet...

I'm asking this because I'm having a `SIGSEGV` problem in a native code written in C to be put in my Android app. Before Android 5, the code run smoothly but in every device using android 5 or superior gives this error ocasionally (sometimes the code runs without error).

Comment: Any reason you're still using r9? The compilers in r9 are quite old and might just have bugs. You also don't have support for the 64-bit architectures in r9. You should try upgrading to r13 (which is about three years newer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the NDK version, it should be fine. It's an older vintage but should still
build your code correctly. I'd try and update as soon as you can though, just to
keep current. I don't think this would be the cause of the crash.

Android 5 introduced [the Android Runtime (ART)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime) by default. Prior to this
the VM used was [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)). I found that the JNI layer in Android 5 was a
lot stricter. In the old Dalvik world you could often get away with, for
example, sharing a JNIEnv pointer between JNI calls. In ART this is not
possible and will always crash. Just to be clear, in Dalvik it should not work
either but you could get away with it, so the mistake went undetected.

Another thing to watch out for is creating large local variables, such as
arrays, on the stack. In Dalvik each thread had 2 stacks, one for JNI code and
one for Java, but in ART the stack is shared between native and Java. So the
JNI code may be running out of stack and crashing. These kinds of crashes can
be very difficult to track down. Code inspection looking for local
(non-malloc'd) arrays has been the way I've found some in the past.

Is there a good stack trace from logcat? Usually you can debug a SIGSEGV by
building in debug and passing the stack trace through [`ndk-stack`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html).
If you're lucky it gives you the line where your code crashes.